# VBA Run Time Error -2147221164(80040154) Class Not Registered

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning, afternoon, evening or whenever you are reading this.

That's the problem, I have a macro and two PC's

- PC One (1): Which Run the macro perfectly.
- PC Two (2) Which drops the error in the title.

The macro Connects SAPLogon, and PC Two breaks in this line:

```
Set Locx = CreateObject("SAP.LogonControl.1")
```

And here is the function:

```
Function SAPLogon() As Boolean
Set Lockx = CreateObject("SAP.LogonControl.1")
Set Conn = Lockx.NewConnection
Conn.Language = "S"
SAPLogon = Conn.logon(0, False)
```

Boths PC have the next exact vba references:

- Visual Basic For Applications
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
- SAP GUI Scripting API

But here is my big suspicion about why the macro doesn't run on PC Two:

*PC One (1) Has Microsoft Office Personal Plus 2016 **32-bit** and PC Two Has Microsoft Office Personal Plus 2016 **64-bit***

The macro has been coded by another employee in 2002 (So I Think it's a 32-bit macro)

The question is:

**Can 64 Bit Excel run 32 Bits Macros? How?**

Thanks and Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149196/sap-query-rfc-connection-on-64bit-win-and-office-activex-component-cant-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the SAP GUI is a 32bit application, and provides 32bit ActiveX controls for scripting in VBA.  These will not work from 64bit Excel, however there is a solution.   The comment above refers to another answer that explains more, but there are two solutions I'll summarise:

1. If you are able to install a new GUI then the latest version, 770 released February 2021 includes an optional install of 64bit NWRFC.  This will install additional 64bit OCX controls that will work from 64bit Excel and VBA. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68906306/5087459).
2. If you need to use an older GUI then you will need to make a registry change using a surrogate as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017544/5087459.